# angular input type="date" set min&max not work in device with ionic

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

max&min attribute works in browser  but not in device with ionic 
here's the code

```
<input type="date" class="item-note item-date text-right" ng-model="vm.expense.date" value="{{vm.expense.date | date: 'yyyy-MM-dd'}}" max="2015-12-18" min="2015-01-18" required>
```

does anyone had this problem?

Comment: May be your caching was the issue. Try `cache-view="false"` in your `ion-view`. Like `<ion-view cache-view="false"></ion-view>`

Comment: http://forum.ionicframework.com/t/date-validation-min-date-not-working/7367/8